# C struct array element initialization casting

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization, compound-literals

Using C99 I'm trying to do this within a function:

```
foo_t foos[4];
foos[0] = {1, {1,2}};
```

doesn't work. So I tried this...

```
foo_t foos[4];
foos[0] = (foo_t){1, {1,2}};
```

which works, but is it safe? Is there not perhaps a better way to do this?

Comment: It would help if you told us what the definition of foo_t is.

Comment: You could do: `foo_t foos[4] = {{1, {1,2}}};`. Though that is not exactly equivalent to what you have shown as it zero intialises the elements at indices 1-3 whereas your example does not.

Comment: In the actual code the foos[] array sits within an even larger array of structs (and contains additional lower level structs within itself), so I'd be unable to do a single assignment during declaration as the resulting excessive nesting would make the whole table an unintelligible mess.

Answer (score 1):

The first case failed, because there no *type* associated with the expression (brace enclosed initializer)

Yes, the second code is safe, as long as the initializer list matches the expected types for the LHS. This is called [compound literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals), FWIW.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.5

> A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized type name followed by a brace enclosed
>   list of initializers is a compound literal. It provides an unnamed object whose value is given by the initializer list.